# 'majority' vs 'great majority'

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning among 'majority', 'great majority' and 'vast majority' in phrases like

> 1) the majority of people
>
> 2) the great majority of people

?

Answer (score 2):

**"Majority" means "the largest group".**

In most cases, it means "over 50%".

In some cases, it is instead used for "the largest group (out of three or more), none of which is over 50%". A more formal word for this is "plurality", which is used in cases (like elections) where the difference is important.

**"Vast majority" and "great majority" mean "the largest group by a big margin".**

"Vast" and "great", as well as other words like "huge" and "overwhelming", are *intensifiers*, emphasising the size of the majority.

In 1000 people, 501 are a majority, but only by two people. (We can call this a "slim majority".) 600 or 700 people is a greater majority. 999 is a huge majority.

There is no rule for exactly what percentage makes a "great" or "vast" majority. It will depend on context. In some polls, it would be very rare to get even 60% agreement on something, so 60% might be called a "great majority". In other cases, you could expect a "great majority" to be 80%, or 90%, or even 99%.

You wouldn't use "majority" for 100%, though. "Majority" implies that there is also a "minority", a smaller group with a different opinion (or other characteristic).

---

And since it came up in another answer, **"absolute majority" is a technical term, not an intensifier.**

Its exact meaning can vary, but it generally means something like "a majority of everyone, not just those present". An example would be a committee of, say, 50 people. If only 40 people show up one day, then 21 people is a majority of the people present. However, some votes might require an "absolute majority", which is always 26 or more people.

Comment: “Only by **two** people”? Why not by a **one** person?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko because if the split is 500/500, there is *no* majority, and if the split is 499/501 then the difference is two.

Comment: When there is numerical percentage defined that is larger than 50%, it's usually called a **supermajority**.  For example, "A vote to end a Senate filibuster must achieve a **supermajority** of 60% to be successful."

Answer (score 0):

**Majority** means "more than half". See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority).

Great Majority is usually referred to as **vast majority**. It is used for percents above 75%, or even above 90%. However, there is no consensus over the required percentage.

Relative to each other, expressed in percents, great majority is greater than majority.

Comment: This is incorrect: "absolute majority" does not mean "everybody". And I would be hesitant to try assigning any particular percentage to "great majority" and "vast majority"!

Comment: @TimPederick: you are right, I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The word "**Great**" simply adds more strength to the number of majority, as compared to simple majority.

***For example***, if majority is a few hundreds of people, **Great majority** could be thousands or even millions.

Comment: While your explanation is not completely wrong, you got some details wrong. And you provided no reference, no back-up to support your claims. They would have helped you to prepare a better answer.